# Crop a PNG image to its minimum size

Tags: python, image, png

How to cut off the blank border area of a PNG image and shrink it to its minimum size using Python?

NB: The border size is not a fixed value, but may vary per image.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)'s [getbbox](http://web.archive.org/web/20130601082832/http://www.pythonware.com:80/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) is working for me

> im.getbbox() => 4-tuple or None
>
> Calculates the bounding box of the
>   non-zero regions in the image. The
>   bounding box is returned as a 4-tuple
>   defining the left, upper, right, and
>   lower pixel coordinate. If the image
>   is completely empty, this method
>   returns None.

Code Sample that I tried, I have tested with bmp, but it should work for png too.

```
import Image
im = Image.open("test.bmp")
im.size  # (364, 471)
im.getbbox()  # (64, 89, 278, 267)
im2 = im.crop(im.getbbox())
im2.size  # (214, 178)
im2.save("test2.bmp")
```

Comment: It seems it does not work for PNG files (made with MSPaint for example). Maybe because of transparence or something else?

Comment: @YOU why does im.getbbox() returns these numbers for a newly opened image instead of (0, 0, 364, 471)? Why aren't the first two numbers zeros?

Answer (score 7):

Here is ready-to-use solution:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def bbox(im):
    a = np.array(im)[:,:,:3]  # keep RGB only
    m = np.any(a != [255, 255, 255], axis=2)
    coords = np.argwhere(m)
    y0, x0, y1, x1 = *np.min(coords, axis=0), *np.max(coords, axis=0)
    return (x0, y0, x1+1, y1+1)

im = Image.open('test.png')
print(bbox(im))  # (33, 12, 223, 80)
im2 = im.crop(bbox(im))
im2.save('test_cropped.png')
```

Example input ([download link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzowc.png) if you want to try):

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem today. Here is my solution to crop the transparent borders. Just throw this script in your folder with your batch .png files:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from os import listdir

def crop(png_image_name):
    pil_image = Image.open(png_image_name)
    np_array = np.array(pil_image)
    blank_px = [255, 255, 255, 0]
    mask = np_array != blank_px
    coords = np.argwhere(mask)
    x0, y0, z0 = coords.min(axis=0)
    x1, y1, z1 = coords.max(axis=0) + 1
    cropped_box = np_array[x0:x1, y0:y1, z0:z1]
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(cropped_box, 'RGBA')
    print(pil_image.width, pil_image.height)
    pil_image.save(png_image_name)
    print(png_image_name)

for f in listdir('.'):
    if f.endswith('.png'):
        crop(f)
```

Comment: This script does not work.

Answer (score 3):

https://gist.github.com/3141140

```
import Image
import sys
import glob

# Trim all png images with alpha in a folder
# Usage "python PNGAlphaTrim.py ../someFolder"

try:
    folderName = sys.argv[1]
except :
    print "Usage: python PNGPNGAlphaTrim.py ../someFolder"
    sys.exit(1)

filePaths = glob.glob(folderName + "/*.png") #search for all png images in the folder

for filePath in filePaths:
    image=Image.open(filePath)
    image.load()

    imageSize = image.size
    imageBox = image.getbbox()

    imageComponents = image.split()

    if len(imageComponents) < 4: continue #don't process images without alpha

    rgbImage = Image.new("RGB", imageSize, (0,0,0))
    rgbImage.paste(image, mask=imageComponents[3])
    croppedBox = rgbImage.getbbox()

    if imageBox != croppedBox:
        cropped=image.crop(croppedBox)
        print filePath, "Size:", imageSize, "New Size:",croppedBox
        cropped.save(filePath)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's necessary to supplement @Frank Krueger's answer.  He makes a good point, but it doesn't include how to properly crop extra border color out of an image. I found that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615901/trim-whitespace-using-pil/10616717#10616717).  Specifically, I found this useful:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

def trim(im):
    bg = Image.new(im.mode, im.size, im.getpixel((0,0)))
    diff = ImageChops.difference(im, bg)
    diff = ImageChops.add(diff, diff, 2.0, -100)
    bbox = diff.getbbox()
    if bbox:
        return im.crop(bbox)

im = Image.open("bord3.jpg")
im = trim(im)
im.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to find rows and cols of your image that are made up purely of your border color.

Using this information, you can easily determine the extents of the inlaid image.

PIL again will then allow you to crop the image to remove the border.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not work for me while writing a Blender script (cannot use PIL), so maybe someone else will find this useful.

```
import numpy as np

def crop(crop_file):
    """crop the image, removing invisible borders"""
    image = bpy.data.images.load(crop_file, check_existing=False)
    w, h = image.size

    print("Original size: " + str(w) + " x " + str(h))

    linear_pixels = image.pixels[:]
    pixels4d = np.reshape(linear_pixels, (h, w, 4))
    
    mask = pixels4d [:,:,3] != 0.
    coords = np.argwhere(mask)
    y0, x0 = coords.min(axis=0)
    y1, x1 = coords.max(axis=0) + 1
    cropped_box = pixels4d[y0:y1, x0:x1, :]
    
    w1, h1 = x1 - x0, y1 - y0
    print("Crop size: " + str(w1) + " x " + str(h1))
    
    temp_image = bpy.data.images.new(crop_file, alpha=True, width=w1, height=h1)
    temp_image.pixels[:] = cropped_box.ravel()
    temp_image.filepath_raw = crop_file
    temp_image.file_format = 'PNG'
    temp_image.alpha_mode = 'STRAIGHT'
    temp_image.save()
```

Comment: What is `bpy` in a line `image = bpy.data.images.load(crop_file, check_existing=False)`?

Comment: @ValeriyVan bpy is blender api to access blender data