# Automatically cropping an image with python/PIL

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, crop

Can anyone help me figure out what's happening in my image auto-cropping script? I have a png image with a large transparent area/space.  I would like to be able to automatically crop that space out and leave the essentials.  Original image has a squared canvas, optimally it would be rectangular, encapsulating just the molecule.

here's the original image:
[image: Original Image]

Doing some googling i came across PIL/python code that was reported to work, however in my hands, running the code below over-crops the image.

```
import Image
import sys

image=Image.open('L_2d.png')
image.load()

imageSize = image.size
imageBox = image.getbbox()

imageComponents = image.split()

rgbImage = Image.new("RGB", imageSize, (0,0,0))
rgbImage.paste(image, mask=imageComponents[3])
croppedBox = rgbImage.getbbox()
print imageBox
print croppedBox
if imageBox != croppedBox:
    cropped=image.crop(croppedBox)
    print 'L_2d.png:', "Size:", imageSize, "New Size:",croppedBox
    cropped.save('L_2d_cropped.png')
```

the output is this:[image: script's output]

Can anyone more familiar with image-processing/PLI can help me figure out the issue?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use numpy, convert the image to array, find all non-empty columns and rows and then create an image from these:

```
import Image
import numpy as np

image=Image.open('L_2d.png')
image.load()

image_data = np.asarray(image)
image_data_bw = image_data.max(axis=2)
non_empty_columns = np.where(image_data_bw.max(axis=0)>0)[0]
non_empty_rows = np.where(image_data_bw.max(axis=1)>0)[0]
cropBox = (min(non_empty_rows), max(non_empty_rows), min(non_empty_columns), max(non_empty_columns))

image_data_new = image_data[cropBox[0]:cropBox[1]+1, cropBox[2]:cropBox[3]+1 , :]

new_image = Image.fromarray(image_data_new)
new_image.save('L_2d_cropped.png')
```

The result looks like
[image: cropped image]

If anything is unclear, just ask.

Comment: `(...)cropBox[2]:cropBox[3]+1 , :]` <-- +1 for this smile :) I'm new to Python... :P

Comment: This method works with Python3 if importing `Image` as `from PIL import Image` (having installed [`PILLOW`](https://python-pillow.org/)  for Python3).

Comment: This works like a charm for RGB and RGBA images but doesn't work with P Mode images.. can you please advise?

Comment: @user12345, I'm not sure what you mean by p Mode images. Please explain. Do you have any examples?

Comment: Slight correction that fixed this for me in edge cases:
Change
`image_data_bw = image_data.max(axis=2)`
to
`image_data_bw = image_data.take(3, axis=2)`
So it actually looks at the transparency value

Comment: This wasn't even the problem/solution I was looking for, but I have to upvote because of the brilliant and simple solution.

Comment: in most images the background is white; the provided code assumes that the background is black; replace the line with `image_data_bw = 255 - image_data.max(axis=2)` to invert the bw image

Comment: this said, the provided code snippet is quite elegant and effective, I am using to extract paragraphs from a PDF file

Answer (score 56):

Install [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/)

```
pip install Pillow
```

and use as

```py
from PIL import Image
    
image=Image.open('L_2d.png')

imageBox = image.getbbox()
cropped = image.crop(imageBox)
cropped.save('L_2d_cropped.png')
```

When you search for boundaries by `mask=imageComponents[3]`, you search only by blue channel.

Comment: upvote, although, the numpy-find-all-empty-cols-rows way is much more interesting.

Comment: If this didn't work, it could be because the "blank" areas of your image are opaque white (255) rather than transparent (0).

Comment: FYI, whoever wants to know: `pip install pillow`

Comment: Use `from PIL import Image` after installing `pillow`.

Comment: @sneawo: What do you mean with `mask=imageComponents[3]`? When I add that as argument for the `image.getbbox()` it complains that `imageComponents` is an unknown variable.

Comment: You may need to invert your image first. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9874342/8930299

Answer (score 24):

I tested most of the answers replied in this post, however, I was ended up my own answer. I used anaconda python3.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

def trim(im):
    bg = Image.new(im.mode, im.size, im.getpixel((0,0)))
    diff = ImageChops.difference(im, bg)
    diff = ImageChops.add(diff, diff, 2.0, -100)
    #Bounding box given as a 4-tuple defining the left, upper, right, and lower pixel coordinates.
    #If the image is completely empty, this method returns None.
    bbox = diff.getbbox()
    if bbox:
        return im.crop(bbox)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bg = Image.open("test.jpg") # The image to be cropped
    new_im = trim(bg)
    new_im.show()
```

Comment: This code has the great advantage to work for any color and alpha.

Comment: I'm having an issue with this particular bit of code while working with low-color images, specifically ones with a single pen and a single canvas color. If the top left pixel happens to be the pen color, it does not generate the mask (you call it diff) correctly. I solved the issue by replacing `im.getpixel((0,0))` with a tuple representing the paper color.

Comment: I used this method, but found that when my background color was white, and the content of the image was near-white, it would get cropped off.  I fixed it by changing the `-100` constant to `0`.

Comment: This method gave me the exact same result as `convert image.png -format "%@" info:` for the bounding box values

Answer (score 6):

Here's another version using [pyvips](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvips).

```py
import sys
import pyvips

image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1])
left, top, width, height = image.find_trim(threshold=2, background=[255, 255, 255])
image = image.crop(left, top, width, height)
image.write_to_file(sys.argv[2])
```

The pyvips trimmer is useful for photographic images. It does a median filter, subtracts the background, finds pixels over the threshold, and removes up to the first and last row and column outside this set. The median and threshold mean it is not thrown off by things like JPEG compression, where noise or invisible compression artefacts can confuse other trimmers.

If you don't supply the `background` argument, it uses the pixel at (0, 0). `threshold` defaults to 10, which is about right for JPEG.

Here it is running on an [8k x 8k pixel NASA earth image](https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/79000/79790/city_lights_asia_night_8k.jpg):

```
$ time ./trim.py /data/john/pics/city_lights_asia_night_8k.jpg x.jpg
real    0m1.868s
user    0m13.204s
sys     0m0.280s
peak memory: 100mb
```

Before:

[image: Earth at night before crop]

After:

[image: Earth after crop]

There's a [blog post with some more discussion here](http://libvips.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/trim-auto-crop-with-ruby-vips.html).

Answer (score 4):

This is an improvement over snew's reply, which works for transparent background. With `mathematical morphology` we can make it work on white background (instead of transparent), with the following code:

```
from PIL import Image
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.morphology import convex_hull_image
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
im = imread('L_2d.jpg')
plt.imshow(im)
plt.title('input image')
plt.show()
# create a binary image
im1 = 1 - rgb2gray(im)
threshold = 0.5
im1[im1 <= threshold] = 0
im1[im1 > threshold] = 1
chull = convex_hull_image(im1)
plt.imshow(chull)
plt.title('convex hull in the binary image')
plt.show()
imageBox = Image.fromarray((chull*255).astype(np.uint8)).getbbox()
cropped = Image.fromarray(im).crop(imageBox)
cropped.save('L_2d_cropped.jpg')
plt.imshow(cropped)
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Came across this post recently and noticed the PIL library has changed.  I re-implemented this with openCV:

```
import cv2

def crop_im(im, padding=0.1):
    """
    Takes cv2 image, im, and padding % as a float, padding,
    and returns cropped image.
    """
    bw = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    rows, cols = bw.shape
    non_empty_columns = np.where(bw.min(axis=0)<255)[0]
    non_empty_rows = np.where(bw.min(axis=1)<255)[0]
    cropBox = (int(min(non_empty_rows) * (1 - padding)),
                int(min(max(non_empty_rows) * (1 + padding), rows)),
                int(min(non_empty_columns) * (1 - padding)),
                int(min(max(non_empty_columns) * (1 + padding), cols)))
    cropped = im[cropBox[0]:cropBox[1]+1, cropBox[2]:cropBox[3]+1 , :]

    return cropped

im = cv2.imread('testimage.png')
cropped = crop_im(im)
cv2.imshow('', cropped)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: This solution works well if you change the type of variables in the cropbox. Currently they're floats, while they should be ints. This gives the error that @Aqua4 got.

Comment: Typecasted to int, error should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

`pilkit` already contains processor for automatic cropping `TrimBorderColor`. SOmething like this should work:

```py
from pilkit.lib import Image
from pilkit.processors import TrimBorderColor

img = Image.open('/path/to/my/image.png')
processor = TrimBorderColor()
new_img = processor.process(img)
```

https://github.com/matthewwithanm/pilkit/blob/b24990167aacbaab3db6d8ec9a02f9ad42856898/pilkit/processors/crop.py#L33

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is old but, for some reason, none of the suggested answers worked for me. So I hacked my own version from existing answers:

```
import Image
import numpy as np
import glob
import shutil
import os

grey_tolerance = 0.7 # (0,1) = crop (more,less)

f = 'test_image.png'
file,ext = os.path.splitext(f)

def get_cropped_line(non_empty_elms,tolerance,S):
    if (sum(non_empty_elms) == 0):
        cropBox = ()
    else:
        non_empty_min = non_empty_elms.argmax()
        non_empty_max = S - non_empty_elms[::-1].argmax()+1
        cropBox = (non_empty_min,non_empty_max)
    return cropBox

def get_cropped_area(image_bw,tol):
    max_val = image_bw.max()
    tolerance = max_val*tol
    non_empty_elms = (image_bw<=tolerance).astype(int)
    S = non_empty_elms.shape
    # Traverse rows
    cropBox = [get_cropped_line(non_empty_elms[k,:],tolerance,S[1]) for k in range(0,S[0])]
    cropBox = filter(None, cropBox)
    xmin = [k[0] for k in cropBox]
    xmax = [k[1] for k in cropBox]
    # Traverse cols
    cropBox = [get_cropped_line(non_empty_elms[:,k],tolerance,S[0]) for k in range(0,S[1])]
    cropBox = filter(None, cropBox)
    ymin = [k[0] for k in cropBox]
    ymax = [k[1] for k in cropBox]
    xmin = min(xmin)
    xmax = max(xmax)
    ymin = min(ymin)
    ymax = max(ymax)
    ymax = ymax-1 # Not sure why this is necessary, but it seems to be.
    cropBox = (ymin, ymax-ymin, xmin, xmax-xmin)
    return cropBox

def auto_crop(f,ext):
    image=Image.open(f)
    image.load()
    image_data = np.asarray(image)
    image_data_bw = image_data[:,:,0]+image_data[:,:,1]+image_data[:,:,2]
    cropBox = get_cropped_area(image_data_bw,grey_tolerance)
    image_data_new = image_data[cropBox[0]:cropBox[1]+1, cropBox[2]:cropBox[3]+1 , :]
    new_image = Image.fromarray(image_data_new)
    f_new = f.replace(ext,'')+'_cropped'+ext
    new_image.save(f_new)
```