# PNG won't autocrop using image.getbbox()

Tags: python, image, crop, bounding-box, python-imaging-library

I've been trying to get this[image: image I want to crop]image to automatically crop to the smallest size possible, removing the transparent bits around it. I can't just crop this image myself manually, as more things will be added on the image like this [image: image I want to crop as well].

I've been using this code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

image=Image.open('headbase1.png')
image.load()

imageSize = image.size
imageBox = image.getbbox()
print(image.getbbox())
cropped=image.crop(imageBox)
cropped.save('headbase_end.png')
```

It does not crop out the transparency around it, and the bounding box is this (0, 0, 45, 45), which I do not think is right.

Thanks, VOT.

Edit, this does work: [Automatically cropping an image with python/PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211340/automatically-cropping-an-image-with-python-pil) with that image, however it refuses to work for my image. .

Comment: The numpy method doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 3):

`getbbox` doesn't work on PNGs with alpha channels: `image.mode == 'RGBA'`

First remove the alpha channel and then obtain the bounding box. `image.convert('RGB').getbbox()`