# Can someone explain me different type of modes of image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

enter image description here[image: Image from PIL module]

I am new to the this image processing stuff. Why I am asking this question is because I have a code which works for RGB mode but doesnt for P mode ?
So I came to conclusion that it is something related to modes. I did some basic research on modes.but did not find any simple explanation. Will be helpful if someone can help me understand this.

CODE:

```
image=Image.open('image.png')
image.load()

image_data = np.asarray(image)
image_data_bw = image_data.max(axis=2)
non_empty_columns = np.where(image_data_bw.max(axis=0)>0)[0]
non_empty_rows = np.where(image_data_bw.max(axis=1)>0)[0]
cropBox = (min(non_empty_rows), max(non_empty_rows), min(non_empty_columns), max(non_empty_columns))

image_data_new = image_data[cropBox[0]:cropBox[1]+1, cropBox[2]:cropBox[3]+1 , :]

new_image = Image.fromarray(image_data_new)
new_image.save('cropped_image.png')
```

[Codesource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211340/automatically-cropping-an-image-with-python-pil)

**Input** to the code following Image:

[image: Image_1]
**Output** should be like the following image(It is cropped to the edges of the picture. Please click on the image for understanding):

[image: Cropped_Image]

This Image is in RGBA mode.so the code is working fine for such images. But not with the image in P mode.

**ERROR:** 
Error I get with P mode:
axis 2 is out of bounds for array of dimension 2

Comment: These modes are not specific to PNG images. They are just different ways to represent image data in digital form.

Comment: Can you look it into it ?

Comment: A palette image has just **one** value per pixel (the RGB colour info is stored in a palette instead, which saves space). The code you found assumes *3* values per pixel.

Comment: Did you look at the other answers? PIL already does the same thing out of the box, correctly for all modes. Using numpy here is overkill, really.

Comment: Your sample input image is a RGB image. What P-mode image do you have that gives you the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you found greatly overcomplicates the process, by using numpy. The PIL library supports this usecase natively, with the `image.getbbox()` and `image.crop()` methods:

```
cropbox = image.getbbox()
new_image = image.crop(cropbox)
```

This works for *all the different modes*, regardless. The cropbox produced by `image.getbbox()` is exactly the same size as the one produced by the numpy route.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. Above thing worked like a charm. I guess it doesnt work for alpha channel,so we need to remove that first then crop the image using getbbox. But for P mode it works perfectly. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('Image.png')

print(x,y)
img.show()
cropbox_1 = img.getbbox()
new_image_1 = img.crop(cropbox_1)
new_image_1.save('Cropped_image,png')
new_image_1.show()
```

This code completely crops the image to the edges. Only if the images are having alpha channel, you might have to remove that channel by converting it.

ex. If it is a RGBA mode make it RGB and then use `getbbox()`.

```
img = image.convert('RGB')
cropbox = img.getbbox()
image_1 = img.crop(cropbox)
```

addition of this should do the task.