# I want to remove unwanted white border of the images of different sizes

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have several images in folder and I want to crop those images. Images have different white space around and I want to remove that. Basically I want to crop unwanted white portion of the images. Please if someone can help with vba code for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of something like python for cases like this.
Python has many a great library for working with images.
[This might be a solution to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211340/automatically-cropping-an-image-with-python-pil/51703287)

Comment: Thanks Hounsvad foir your answer. I have restriction to use python and other language too. All I can use is Excel VBA or Perl Script.