# Animated GIF trim whitespaces using PIL

Tags: python, imagemagick, gif, trim, animated-gif

Using the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10616717/8166528, I can trim the whitespaces, however this method takes the first frame and trims it. So the animated gif will lose the remaining frames.

Is there a way to trim the whitespaces of an animated gif?

Added picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMvK3.gif

Comment: If you are willing to use ImageMagick, it can do the job very nicely. If you post an example animated gif, I can show you the command line to do that.

Comment: @fmw42 i've added a gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using ImageMagick like @fmw42 suggested:

```
convert input.gif -trim +repage output.gif
```