# Trim the whitespace of the grayscale image

Tags: python, image, numpy, deep-learning

[image like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmFhK.jpg)

I get a images set, and the images are like this.

How can I remove the beneath white part of the image using python, which doesn't contain any useful content?

I read the image to numpy array in python.

My code is like this:

```
data_dir = "/Users/leon/Projects/inpainting/data/"
images = []
files = glob.glob (data_dir + "*.jpg")
for file in files:
    image = cv2.imread(file, 0)
    images.append(image)
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I'm thinking using two for loop to check the pixel element, but I got 5,000  images like this, will it be to slow to do it in this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615901/trim-whitespace-using-pil/10616717

Comment: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/removing-0s-from-2d-arrays.884140/ see last part

Comment: thank you guys but I find a better way to do it, see my answer blew.

Answer (score 1):

This trims white space row-wise both above and below (actually it trims any full white row):

```
trimmed = image[np.where(~np.all(image == 255, axis=1))]
```

If you need to trim just the top and bottom margins you can do:

```
empty_row_mask = np.all(image == 255, axis=1)
top = np.searchsorted(~empty_row_mask, True)
bottom = np.searchsorted(empty_row_mask, True)
trimmed = image[top:bottom]
```

Comment: thank you, I find a way which can find the most suitable window for trimming the undesired white part both sides

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to do it using openCV3 and python3.6

```
image_neg = cv2.bitwise_not(image) # invert the root to white
coords = cv2.findNonZero(image_neg) # find all the non-zero points (root)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(coords) # find minimum spanning bounding box
rect = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```