# How replace transparent with a color in pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

I need to replace the transparency layer of a png image with a color white. I tried this

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('test.png')
new_image = image.convert('RGB', colors=255)
new_image.save('test.jpg', quality=75)
```

but the transparency layer turned black. Anyone can help me?

Comment: The transparency layer doesn't have a colour - it only indicates how transparent a pixel is.

Answer (score 36):

Paste the image on a completely white rgba background, then convert it to jpeg.

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('test.png')
new_image = Image.new("RGBA", image.size, "WHITE") # Create a white rgba background
new_image.paste(image, (0, 0), image)              # Paste the image on the background. Go to the links given below for details.
new_image.convert('RGB').save('test.jpg', "JPEG")  # Save as JPEG
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5324782/6900838) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/7u1z6u/how_to_paste_transparent_image_into_white/).

Answer (score 8):

The other answers gave me a `Bad transparency mask` error. The solution is to make sure the original image is in RGBA mode.

```
image = Image.open("test.png").convert("RGBA")
new_image = Image.new("RGBA", image.size, "WHITE")
new_image.paste(image, mask=image)

new_image.convert("RGB").save("test.jpg")
```