# ImageMagic detect if the image has border or frame

Tags: java, image-processing, imagemagick

Basically, I have a image with a thick yellow border around it something like NetGeo image. I want to check if there is border or not **(NetGeo is just an example, border color can be of any width and any color)**, I want to detect that and shave it if it exists.

I see this question is been answered in [Trim whitespace using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615901/trim-whitespace-using-pil/10616717#10616717) for PIL but I am looking for same solution in imagemagick with a single command or java

[image]

But I don't want to crop the image if there is not solid border.

For example
[image]

I don't want to remove the yellow color as it is not a solid lined border. Hope it helps to understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to work in ImageMagick

```
convert NG.png -fuzz 20% -background "rgb(239,204,60)" -define trim:percent-background=0% -trim +repage x.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for the answer. I really appreciate, this works well if I know the color, what if I don't know the color of the border? My main task is to know if the image has a border or not or only trim if the image has order. This fails if the the image doesn't have one.

Comment: Just measure the color at the top left corner of the image as `convert logo: -format "%[pixel:p{0,0}]" info:`

Comment: Thanks @fmw42 above command helps me to find the color and remove it from the image but, it also crops if the there is not solid border. I just want to crop if only there is a border like the one in NP. Let me update the question to help

Comment: First crop the input on each side how ever many pixels wide you want (even just 1 or 2 pixel). Then -append the top and bottom and the 90 deg rotated left and right into one image. Then append each of the 3 channel into one grayscale channel and get the average ( -format "%[fx: mean>0?0:1]" info:). So if the result is 0, it has a border. I the result is 1, it does not have a border. Or you can set a threshold for the border test as -format "%[fx: mean>threshold?0:1]" info:v

Comment: Thanks for reply again, m not very versed with imagemagic but will give it a try

Comment: Let me know if you have problems with my suggestions. I have not had time to verify that they work.