# Unable to crop away transparency, Neither PIL getbbox() nor Numpy are working

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I've very much a noob when it comes to image processing :( 
I have a bunch of PNG files (300 of them) that have large areas of transparency that I wish to crop. I want to automate the process obviously, hence why i tried using python and PIL.

Now I have a look at the following link,
[Crop a PNG image to its minimum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905421/crop-a-png-image-to-its-minimum-size), and also using Numpy as suggested by this link, [Automatically cropping an image with python/PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211340/automatically-cropping-an-image-with-python-pil#), both to no success :( The output files are identical to the input files! no cropping of the transparency, same size. The getbbox is returning same width and height.

Here's a link to one of those images; [98x50button](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxHUSI3XRV0_dUU0aE9DUDU1R1k/view?usp=sharing)
The image is of a button icon in the shape of a bell. it's drawn in white so it's hard to see which transparent background. The expected outcome would a 20x17 Button (with the transparency inside that 20x17 box remaining in tact)

Here's the code i'm using;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import Image
import numpy as np


def autocrop_image2(image):
    image.load()

    image_data = np.asarray(image)
    image_data_bw = image_data.max(axis=2)
    non_empty_columns = np.where(image_data_bw.max(axis=0) > 0)[0]
    non_empty_rows = np.where(image_data_bw.max(axis=1) > 0)[0]
    cropBox = (min(non_empty_rows), max(non_empty_rows),
               min(non_empty_columns), max(non_empty_columns))

    image_data_new = image_data[cropBox[0]:cropBox[
        1] + 1, cropBox[2]:cropBox[3] + 1, :]

    new_image = Image.fromarray(image_data_new)
    return new_image


def autocrop_image(image, border=0):
    # Get the bounding box
    bbox = image.getbbox()

    # Crop the image to the contents of the bounding box
    image = image.crop(bbox)

    # Determine the width and height of the cropped image
    (width, height) = image.size

    # Add border
    width += border * 2
    height += border * 2

    # Create a new image object for the output image
    cropped_image = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), (0, 0, 0, 0))

    # Paste the cropped image onto the new image
    cropped_image.paste(image, (border, border))

    # Done!
    return cropped_image

walk_dir = sys.argv[1]

print('walk_dir = ' + walk_dir)

# If your current working directory may change during script execution, it's recommended to
# immediately convert program arguments to an absolute path. Then the variable root below will
# be an absolute path as well. Example:
# walk_dir = os.path.abspath(walk_dir)
print('walk_dir (absolute) = ' + os.path.abspath(walk_dir))

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(walk_dir):
    print('--\nroot = ' + root)
    list_file_path = os.path.join(root, 'my-directory-list.txt')
    print('list_file_path = ' + list_file_path)

    with open(list_file_path, 'wb') as list_file:
        for subdir in subdirs:
            print('\t- subdirectory ' + subdir)

        for filename in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)

            print('\t- file %s (full path: %s)' % (filename, file_path))
            filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
            if file_extension.lower().endswith('.png'):
                # Open the input image
                image = Image.open(file_path)
                # Do the cropping
                # image = autocrop_image(image, 0)
                new_image = autocrop_image2(image)
                # Save the output image
                output = os.path.join("output", filename + ".png")
                print output
                new_image.save(output)
```

Thank you all for the help :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "no success" means? What happens when you use the code on your files?

Comment: The output files are identical to the input files, in look and in size.

Comment: crop transparency? remove transparency? save it as jpg?

Comment: Crop transparency, the expected outcome of the 98x50 button is a  20x17Button (with transparency inside that box remaining) Sorry if this wasn't clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue you're having is that your images contain transparent white pixels, and your code is only going to crop pixels that are both transparent *and* black. The RGBA values for most of the pixels in your example image are `(255, 255, 255, 0)`.

In `autocrop_image2`, you're taking the `max` of the channel values. You probably just want the alpha channel's value directly, so change:

```
image_data_bw = image_data.max(axis=2)
```

To:

```
image_data_bw = image_data[:,:,3]
```

The rest of the function should then work as intended.

The `autocrop_image` function has the same problem. The `getbbox` method returns the bounds of the non-zero pixels, and transparent white pixels are not zero. To fix it, try converting the image from `"RGBA"` mode to premultiplied alpha `"RGBa"` mode  before finding the bounding box:

```
bbox = image.convert("RGBa").getbbox()
```

Comment: I will accept your answer, as it's cleaner than the answer i just came up with. In the autocrop_image function, I replaced the image.getbbox() with a function that does the following; 
def getbbox(image):
    alphaData = image.tostring("raw", "A")
    alphaImage = Image.fromstring("L", image.size, alphaData)

    return alphaImage.getbbox()

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution to crop the transparent borders.
Just throw this script in your folder with your batch .png files:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from os import listdir

def crop(image_name):
    pil_image = Image.open(image_name)
    np_array = np.array(pil_image)
    blank_px = [255, 255, 255, 0]
    mask = np_array != blank_px
    coords = np.argwhere(mask)
    x0, y0, z0 = coords.min(axis=0)
    x1, y1, z1 = coords.max(axis=0) + 1
    cropped_box = np_array[x0:x1, y0:y1, z0:z1]
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(cropped_box, 'RGBA')
    print(pil_image.width, pil_image.height)
    pil_image.save(png_image_name)
    print(png_image_name)

for f in listdir('.'):
    if f.endswith('.png'):
        crop(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a new solution; I just ran into this problem:

You have an RGBA image:

- When the pixel's A is 0, the cell should be fully transparent,
- but some of your pixels have A as 0, and RGB values not zero.
- Pillow's getbbox() and other functions now fail.
- You want to force your RGB to 0 whenever alpha is 0

So:

- Make a pure black RGBA image, each pixel being (0, 0, 0, 0)
- Make a composite with your image and an RGBA black image, using your 
  image as a mask.
- Wherever your A was 0, your RGB will now be zero
- This is a solution; there is probably a lower-memory solution.

Here is the code:

```
black = Image.new('RGBA', myImage.size)
myImage = Image.composite(myImage, black, myImage)
myCroppedImage = myImage.crop(myImage.getbbox())
```