# Python add padding to images that need it

Tags: python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

I have a bunch of images that aren't equal size, and where some fit entirely to the frame and some have blank padding.

I would like to know how I can resize each of them to be the same image size and to have roughly the same border size.

Currently I am doing

```py
from PIL import Image
from glob import glob

images = glob('src/assets/emotes/medals/**/*.png', recursive=True)

for image_path in images:
    im = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGBA')
    im = im.resize((100, 100))
    im.save(image_path)
```

but this doesn't account for a possible border.

**Image 1 - 101 x 101**
[image: image 1 w/ border]
[image: image 1]

**Image 2 - 132 x 160**
[image: image 2 w/ border]
[image: image 2]

**Desired result - 100 x 100**
[image: desired 1 w/ border]
[image: desired 1]

[image: desired 2 w/ border]
[image: desired 2]

Images arent always bigger than `(100, 100)` so I will need to use resize.

I can also maybe remove the PNG border for all images, and then resize which might be easier.

Comment: As far as I know, `im.getbbox()` will give u the original image without the transparent background. But this seems to go in similar direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905421/crop-a-png-image-to-its-minimum-size

Comment: thank you that works, could you post that as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [Crop a PNG image to its minimum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905421/crop-a-png-image-to-its-minimum-size),  `im.getbbox()` will give you the original image without transparent background.

Documentation : [Pillow (PIL Fork)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getbbox)